# Egg yolk substitute for whole eggs in strata

Tags: substitutions, eggs, yolk

Can I use egg yolks for all or part of whole eggs in strata?

Comment: what is strata ? can you share a recipe ?

Comment: Are you talking about stracciatella?

Comment: To those who haven't encountered it, strata is the correct term, and has nothing to do with a stracciatella. It is a type of baked good with filling. I see no need to close the question, any more than you would close if the OP had asked about a quiche instead of a strata.

Comment: Thanks for the spelling correction. Still wondering if using yolks in place of whole eggs will be problem with the structure. Recipe calls for 7eggs so wondering if I can use some of yolks left over from the meringue I am also making.